# use the URL to press the "accept" Button (javascript) automaticaly while call a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, url

I've build a javascipt code that popup's a policy which a visitor has to accept.
This is working fine but now I will use some systemAccounts and they will not accept this on their own.

Now I hope that I can find a solution in customizing my URL String. I want to creat a "https://www.url.de/xyz/?pressButtonAutomaticaly?goToNextPage" String

I hope you can give me a hint, all I found was about "createButton"

Here is the code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

        function getConfirmation(){

           var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue by accepting  Policy ?");
           if( retVal == true ){
              document.write ("User wants to continue!");
                   // window.location = "URL";
                    window.location = "URL";
              return true;
           }
           else{
              document.write ("You have Not Accepted Download Policy!");
                    window.close();

              return false;


           }
        }

  </script>
```

Thank you and best wishes,
Nils

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `window.location.search` property to check if your query string parameters are there and then take action accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for your needs better?

```
function continueOn() {
    document.write("User wants to continue!");
    window.location = "URL";
    return true;
}

function getConfirmation() {
    var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue by accepting  Policy ?");
    if( retVal == true ){
        return continueOn();
    }
    else{
        document.write ("You have Not Accepted Download Policy!");
        window.close();
        return false;
    }
}

function autoClickButton(queryString) {
    if (queryString.indexOf('pressButtonAutomatically') > -1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function init(queryString) {
    if (autoClickButton(queryString)) {
        continueOn();
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', getConfirmation);
    }
}

init(window.location.search);
```